# Html form is not working with Php, Ajax request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Hello following is my html form which I want to validate with Ajax. So that Browser do not load the page. If user enter First Name, It's should show the first name above the html form. But It doesn't showing...

**Html form:**

```
<form id="validation"/>
<table width="500" border="0" cellspacing="10" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td>First Name</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="fname" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['fname'])) echo $_POST['fname']; ?>" class="tr" placeholder="First Name"/></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><input type="reset" name="reset" value="Clear" class="submit"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="submit" name="Submit" id="submit" value="Registration" class="submit"/></td>
  </tr>
</table>    
</form>
<script>
    $('#validation').submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'regProcess.php',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {                    
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Php code:**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['Submit']) && $_POST['Submit'] == "Registration"){
    $fname =  $_POST['fname'];
    echo $fname;        
    }
?>
```

Comment: Why would it  show anything, you're not doing anything with the returned data ?

Comment: Try `success: function (data) { alert(data); }`, you need to do something with the returned data.

Comment: You closed your form tag at line 1

Comment: I don't think the `Submit` field is included when you use `serialize()`, so that check in the PHP won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Near the bottom of your code, you have this:

```
            success: function (data) {                    
        }
```

That's your problem.  You're not doing anything with the returned "data" - you need to use javascript or jquery to insert it into the DOM somewhere.
EDIT: UPDATE

To use jquery to insert the data into the dom, do something like this:

```
            success: function (data) {                    
                $("#id of the element where you want the data").innerHTML+=data
            }
```

That will append the "data" retrieved from the AJAX into the element with the specific ID.  You can use any CSS selector inside the $("HERE") I believe.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Actually I'm new in Jquery. Can you show how do i show the error above the form ?

Comment: Well, did you see my php code..if its get the fname then it's should show the "First Name" above the form. So is it possible ?

Comment: That's possible.  I would suggest putting a `<div>` or other element with a specific ID above the form.

Comment: something like : `success: function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    $('#info1').html(data.msg);
   }`

Comment: That should overwrite the innerHTML of an element with the ID "info1" with the contents of "data.msg," as well as logging the data to the console.

Comment: If it's still not working, try this:
`success: function (data) { alert(data); }` - that should just alert any data returned by the ajax.

Comment: Then "regProcess.php" is not returning any data.  Are you seeing any errors in the javascript console?

Comment: NO regProcess.php is not returning any data and there is not error in console.

Comment: So, now you need to figure out why "regProcess.php" is not returning data.  Could it be you forgot to "echo" it?  The AJAX will retrieve the effective (post-php) HTML of the page you are trying to load.

Comment: When you access "regProcess.php" directly, do you see any data?  Is HTML sent to the browser?

Comment: Not I don't see any data. Just whole blank page.

Comment: Then that's all the AJAX will see, too.  Look through the PHP for that page and see if you can find why none of the data is displaying.  Once you get it displaying, the AJAX should work.

Comment: could you please give me final code that will work on your localhost ?

Comment: I don't have any of the PHP behind "regProcess.php" - but if "regProcess.php" consisted solely of `<?php echo "Hello"; ?>` then the AJAX would retrieve "HELLO" when you performed the request.  Because "regProcess.php" is apparently not outputting anything, the AJAX can't retrieve anything.